# How to pass database between activities

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

Im trying to use my database in multiple activities and have read the questions posted on here but it either left me still confused, or they were passing text through an intent instead of passing a whole SQLiteDatabase. I heard using a Content Provider was good but android states not to use this for passing a database between activities in the same application

"Before you start building a provider, do the following:

Decide if you need a content provider. You need to build a content provider if you want to provide one or more of the following features:

You want to offer complex data or files to other applications.

You want to allow users to copy complex data from your app into other apps.

You want to provide custom search suggestions using the search framework.

**You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application.**"

If i knew where to start or had code i would post it but i don't know where to start with this. I am creating an sms app and need to pass database from the Main Activity to the Conversation Activity. All help is appreciated.

```
package com.swavey.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<smsDatabase> dbs;
    private SMSList<SMS> smsList;
    private ArrayList<String> smsAddressList;
    private final String firstRun = "initRun";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        //check if first run to try and run initsync or upgrade
        if (!prefs.contains(firstRun)) {
            Sync();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean(firstRun, true);
        }

        populateThreads();


    }


    public void Sync() {
    }

    private void upgradeSync(Cursor cursor) {

    }


    private void initialSync(Cursor c) {

    }

    private SMS addText(Cursor c) {
        SMS txt = new SMS();
        txt.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
        txt.set_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        txt.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")));
        txt.setType(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));
        txt.setAddress(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));
        txt.setRead(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
        txt.setSeen(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("seen")));
        txt.setSubject(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("subject")));
        txt.setThread_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("thread_id")));
        txt.setPerson(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("person")));
        txt.setProtocol(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("protocol")));
        txt.setServiceCenter(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("service_center")));
        return txt;
    }

    public void populateThreads() {
        /*number of threads is number of smsAddressList
        first line is from addressList
        second is form first "date dsc" text of respective database
        left is pic
         */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new MainListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.threads);
        list.setAdapter(adapter1);



    }

    private class MainListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MainListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.sms_listview_layout, smsAddressList);
        }

        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sms_listview_layout, parent, false);
            }

            // assigns address
            String currentAddress = smsAddressList.get(position);
            TextView bigView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            bigView.setText(currentAddress);

            //assigns subject
            dbs.get(position).open();
            String subject = dbs.get(position).getSubject();
            dbs.get(position).close();
            TextView lilView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            lilView.setText(subject);

            //assigns picture


            return itemView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } if (id == R.id.action_sync) {
            Sync();
        }
         if (id == R.id.loadtexts) {
            populateThreads();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.swavey.testing;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.security.KeyChain;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Adrian on 11/5/2014.
 */
public class smsDatabase  {

    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final int COLUMN_ID =0;

    // database info
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "texts";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    // list of fields
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_READ = "read";
    private static final String KEY_THREADID = "thread_id";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_SEEN = "seen";

    //list of field numbers
    private static final int COL_ADDRESS = 1;
    private static final int COL_BODY = 2;
    private static final int COL_DATE = 3;
    private static final int COL_READ = 4;
    private static final int COL_THREADID = 5;
    private static final int COL_TYPE = 6;
    private static final int COL_SEEN = 7;

    //create string array of all fields;
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE,
         KEY_READ, KEY_THREADID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_SEEN};


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +KEY_ADDRESS + " text not null, "
            +KEY_BODY + " text not null, "
            +KEY_DATE + " text not null, "
            +KEY_READ+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_THREADID+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_TYPE+ " text not null, "
            +KEY_SEEN+ " text not null"
            + ");";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public smsDatabase (Context cxt) {
        this.context = cxt;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    //open database
    public smsDatabase open() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    //close database
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //returns a cursor with all rows loaded
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
        null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    /*
    LEARN HOW OT FIND NUMBER OF THREAD IDS. CREATE NUMBER OF THREAD IDS DIFFERENT DATABASES
    USE ARRAY LIST TO KNOW ADDRESSS OF DIFFERENT THREADS
    DISPLAY ARRAY LIST IN LISTVIEW
    USER OPENS CONVO WHICH READS FROM THAT DATABASE

     */

    // insert sms into table
    public long insertSMS (SMS sms) {
        ContentValues iv = new ContentValues();
        iv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, sms.getAddress());
        iv.put(KEY_BODY, sms.getBody());
        iv.put(KEY_DATE, sms.getDate());
        iv.put(KEY_READ, sms.getRead());
        iv.put(KEY_THREADID, sms.getThread_id());
        iv.put(KEY_TYPE, sms.getType());
        iv.put(KEY_SEEN, sms.getSeen());




        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, iv);
    }

    public Cursor getLast() {
        SMS txt = new SMS();
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToLast();
        return c;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        Cursor c = getLast();
        String sub = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
        if (sub.length() > 30) {
            sub = sub.substring(0, 30) + "...";
            return sub;
        }
        sub = sub +  "...";
        return sub;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }


        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a sqlite database. It is accessible from all your activities. Though, you can pass text/data through an intent. Let's say for example you have an activity named FirstActivity which ask the user his name, then you can pass his name to MainActivity to display his name. You can use sqlite database for storing 'huge' amount of data.

Comment: I already have the databases set up and working. So how would i access them in the secondactivity?

Comment: I presume that you have a class named ScanDAO or something like that. If so, here is how you can use it : `ScanDAO scanDAO = new ScanDAO(this); scanDAO.insert(yourContent); scanDAO.getLatest();...`; Otherwise show me your code.

Comment: i dont have any code relevant to using the database outside of the activity. I posted the code I do have though.

Comment: I think that you need more code than that. Have a look here : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ It's well explained and a ready to use sample.

Comment: I have the database up and running. It works. I can add data to it. Read from it. All of that. I am just wondering how to access the same database in different activities.

Comment: its there. refresh the page

Comment: `smsDatabase db = new smsDatabase(getApplicationContext()); db.open();` db.insert(new SMS()); etc.

Comment: that creats a new database for the current activity.

Comment: This creates an instance of the database.

Comment: It is creating a new database not accessing the one i already created in the MainActivity.

Comment: I am pretty sure that doesn't create a new database, if so you will get an error telling you that your database already exists.

Comment: Why your open fonction return an smsDatabase object? This should be : `public void open() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }`

Comment: Its not working. Also if you look at the top of my Main Activity you can see im using an smsDatabase ArrayList. I need to send a specified database from teh ArrayList to the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Question why aren't you just instantiating smsDatabase in the other Activity?

I won't read too much into that suggestion. It is true that ContentProvider in someways is an overkill but it will provide an off the shelf solution that will sql encapsulation that all the activities in the app can use. You can keep the ContentProvider private so no data will be exposed to the outside.

Comment: Its an smsDatabase ArrayList. I need to send a specified smsDatabase from MainActivity to SecondActivity. Thanks ill look into ContentProvider then.